# How to remove sorting on ui-grid before reload another data set ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Im using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) to load my data set. Here is my requirment;

step 01: I want to load dataset_01 (`scope.gridOptions.data = res_01;`).

step 02: I want to sort by First Name (Click by `firstname` column).

step 03: Click an external button and Reload ui-grid with an another data set (`scope.gridOptions.data = res_02;`).

Here is my result:

[image]

I dont want sort by `First Name` here for second dataset.
I want data without sorting. How can I do it ?

Expected result:

[image]

So I want to reload second data set without sorting (Means I want to remove first sorting before load second data set). how can I reset my ui-grid before load next data set (`scope.gridOptions.data = res_01;`).

How can I do it ?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `sort` property of your `columnDefs` to:

```
sort: {
   direction: undefined,
}
```

and call for grid refresh using `$sope.gridApi.core.refresh()` after. This should re-render the whole grid and get rid of the sorting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've searched everywhere and your answer is what actually worked for me, upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Visit this page: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi

After having instantiated your gridApi, you can just call:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Hey @The JD. Thanks for the reply. But I dont think this would work. I tried and it didnt work as I expected. I think ui-grid do not have a way to clean sorting. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5207

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your gridoption like this

example

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableSelectAll: false,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableFullRowSelection: false,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    enablePaginationControls: false,
    enableRowHashing: false,
    paginationCurrentPage:1,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: "FristName", displayName: "Frist Name", width: '6%', sort: { direction: undefined }  },
    ]
};
```

after that you can remove the sorting where you want using below code

```
$scope.RemoveSorting = function ()
{
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.forEach(function (d) {

        d.sort.direction = undefined;
    })
}
```